# success Build release APK but cant install

Tags: android, mysql, cordova

```
D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy\www>Ionic build android --release
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js" "D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy"

add to body class: platform-android

Running command: cmd "/s /c ""D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --release""

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

Running: D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

:preBuild


:preReleaseBuild
:checkReleaseManifest


:CordovaLib:compileLint


:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:preBuild


:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:bundleRelease

UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedReleaseLibrary

UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild


:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild

:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132340Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase961Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement961Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm961Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid961Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks961Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareReleaseDependencies


:compileReleaseAidl
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileReleaseRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateReleaseAssets
 UP-TO-DATE

:mergeReleaseAssets

UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateReleaseResources

UP-TO-DATE

:mergeReleaseResources


:processReleaseManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:processReleaseResources


:generateReleaseSources

:compileReleaseJava
 UP-TO-DATE

:lintVitalRelease


:compileReleaseNdk
 UP-TO-DATE

:preDexRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:dexRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:processReleaseJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE

:packageRelease


:assembleRelease

:cdvBuildRelease



BUILD SUCCESSFUL


Total time: 10.174 secs

Built the following apk(s):

    D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk


D:\06 ANDROID\hwacademy2 - Copy\www>
```

what miss about me :( ? this firts i build apk . someone help me please.

Comment: If you already have installed app on your phone, delete it and then try to install release version

Comment: app in my phone is uninstalled. then i install my app `app-release-unsigned.apk` in my phone, but i cant, and display error dialog `parse error there was a problem parsing the package` .

Comment: If your app is not signed, you need to sign application. Then your problem will be sorted. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Comment: Ok, thanks dude, i will try hard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install and see the debug version of the App using the command :

**`ionic cordova build android`**  ( ie. without the Release flag --release )

If you want to install and see the Release version of your App, then you need to sign your App using a Key.

**Step 1** : Generate your Private Key ( if you have one, then discard this step ) :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias
```

**Step 2** : Sign your APK

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.jks android-release-unsigned.apk my-alias
```

**Step 3** : Optimize your Apk using Zipalign

```
zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

Refer this Link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/ (Android Section)

Comment: I've done the first step, but when i do the second step.

`Enter Passphrase for keystore:
jarsigner: unable to open jar file: android-release-unsigned.apk`

Comment: Check whether you have 'android-release-unsigned.apk' in the location where you are trying out this command. Also Check if you have entered the correct passphrase for Keystore.

Comment: oh thanks very much Lokkeshwaran, you are right, I am wrong to write the location. and my problem is **solved**

Answer (score 1):

**The generate APK is unsigned (app-release-unsigned.apk). You can only install an unsigned APK on a emulator not a physical device.**

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

This means that the APK has built, it will be located here:

```
Copy\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk
```

then to install run this through terminal (if mac):

```
adb install PASTEHEREYOURPATH.apk
```

**The generate APK is unsigned (app-release-unsigned.apk). You can only install an unsigned APK on a emulator not a physical device.**

Comment: Yes, your right, then i copy that apk to my phone, and i want install, but i cant. you know why, please help me

Comment: what is the error / message displayed when you try and install the apk, make sure debug is enabled on the android phone. You can also check if the device is connected by typing: adb devices

Comment: error displayed is **parse error** `there was a problem parsing the package`.

Comment: The generate APK is unsigned (app-release-unsigned.apk). You can only install an unsigned APK on a emulator not a physical device. You need to generate a signed APK prior to an unsigned version.

Comment: oh, thanks @Luis Ferraiolo. but how. if i want to install my app in my phone `physical device` ??
**What should I do ?**

Comment: You need to first generate a keystone. Here is how to do that: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html After creating this go to android studio. Click Build > Generate Signed APK > Module 'app'